csvstack input folder instead of individual files?
I have 100s of CSVs that total to 150+ GB of data. I want to merge them all into one CSV file, so I can then dump that CSV file into an SQLite database for easier querying.
This stackoverflow post (R - How to combine many .csv files into one without overloading memory?) suggested the csvstack utility to do so, with the ability of just specifying the folder itself and a wildcard filename.
However, this does not seem to work on Windows - I get the error OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '*.csv'. Specifying each file name individually is not an option.
How can I get the wildcard selection working on windows?
I've tried running the utility from inside the folder and just specifying *.csv as input, as well as from outside the folder and specifying folder/*.csv as input.

If there are no header row lines, the easiest way will be from the command line: type PATH_TO_FILES_FOLDER*.csv >> PATH_TOOUTPUT_FOLDER\new_file.csv However if there are headers for every file then the header will be copied to the file repeatedly

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@Ze'evBen-Tsvi Unfortunately there are header lines. This tool was supposed to take care of it, but I assume this is some Unix vs Windows problem, where windows doesn't deal with the wildcard before feeding the input to the tool

This is a simple code to add files assuring that only the first file header is written to the new file. replace the file path with your path to the files' input location, and the file's output location.
import glob

for i, filename in enumerate(glob.glob('data/in/*.csv')):
    with open('data/out/output.csv', 'a') as out:
        with open(filename) as f:
            if i > 0:
                f.readline()
            print(f'Adding file: {filename} to output.csv')
            out.write(f.read())


Wouldn't this read all files into memory since the output file is open the whole time? I have over 150GB of files

@AKnum I truly didn't think about it, so I revised the code replaced the order of the open statement with the for loop, and changed the open mode to 'a' (add). This way it should close the output file after every new file is added to the output end of the file.
